# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'translate' , even after "pip install translate"

Tags: python, docker, pip, fastapi, uvicorn

I am having this error, even after "pip install translate" multiple times.
I am running my application in a docker container. I am a beginner , so please let me know, what mistake i am doing.
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 477, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/./main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from translate import Translator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'translate'
```

`when I am running "python3 -m pip install translate"`

```
Requirement already satisfied: translate in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from translate) (8.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: libretranslatepy==2.1.1 in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from translate) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from translate) (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from translate) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->translate) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->translate) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->translate) (1.26.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->translate) (2022.9.24)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

`
When I did "pip list", translate is there but still this error is coming.

Comment: Did you make sure that you are using the pip of the same python version?
Try running:
which python3
and use the pip3 from that same directory.

Comment: yes, I am using python 3 and I also tried "pip3 install translate"

Comment: What path do you get when running the command:

which pip3

Comment: /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/bin/pip3

Comment: And when running: which python3 ?

Comment: /root/anaconda3/envs/newenvt1/bin/python3

Comment: Hi @NitishRana, welcome to StackOverflow. You can include more details such as endling lines of pip installation log and your Dockerfile or docker commands you may have executed to your question to help us have more information on it. From what you've shared, you can try using `python3 -m pip install translate` to ensure that the same Python's pip installation has happened.

Comment: @HarshitGupta , i edited my question, please check if you can answer now

Comment: How did you run the py file on the first error?

Comment: @ConstantinHong i run this command "uvicorn main:app --reload"

Comment: it is better to use  ve  like pipenv :first install pipenv using pip then install your first module using:pipenv install  then run: pipenv shell  and install other modules then execute your project

Answer (score 0):

You need not local pip install, but install in your docker.

Add to Dockerfile

```
python3 -m pip install translate
```

And rebuild your image

Comment: Actually, I launched the container in interactive mode and installing translate in that but still facing the same problem